# Ignore folders when performing :find command

Tags: path, find

I'm using the `:find` command as my "fuzzy file searcher" in Vim. My setup:

```
set path=,,**
nnoremap <leader>f :find *
```

However, I'm having trouble ignoring folders. Huge folders that contain dependencies, like node_modules, slow down the search a lot and of course pollute the results with things I don't want.

I've tried the following, with no luck:

```
set wildignore+=node_modules/*
set wildignore+=node_modules/**
set wildignore+=node_modules/**/*
```

What do I need to do? Thanks

Comment: How is it possible there isn't a solution for this??

Answer (score 19):

The following enables fuzzy file search (i.e `:find script.js`) through every file in your project root while excluding the `node_modules` dir and its contents.

```
set path+=**                                                                    
set wildignore+=**/node_modules/**
```

Tested on:

*VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 11 2017 13:57:34)
MacOS X (unix) version*
(Compiled by Homebrew)

Comment: `set ` is missing in the second line.

Comment: it seems like this filters out matches in the `node_modules` directory during tab-completion, but doesn't prevent `:find` from searching in there, resulting in a slower `:find`